# Strange equality check using bitwise shift operators

Tags: c++, c, linux, operators, bit-manipulation

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int a, int b)
{
        return ((a>>= b<<= a) ? 1 : 0);
}

void bar(int x, int y)
{
        printf("%d,%d: %s\n",x, y, (foo(x,y) ? "Equal" : "Not Equal"));
}

int main()
{
        bar(0,1);
        bar(4,4);
        bar(3,2);
        bar(9,9);
        bar(-2,-2);
        bar(-8,8);
        return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program is

```
0,1: Not Equal
4,4: Equal
3,2: Not Equal
9,9: Equal
-2,-2: Equal
-8,8: Equal
```

Can you help me in understanding how the **equality check** in function `foo`() works? Why it fails when one argument is positive and another negative? What is the workaround in function `foo`() to display results correctly for all cases i.e. for all negative and positive arguments ?

**EDIT**: From the answers below, results for other values are:

```
70,72: Equal
-2,-2: Equal
64,64: Equal
128,32: Equal
256,250: Not Equal
250,256: Equal
-250,-256: Equal
```

Please explain, why this equality check works for some value sets, and not for others. What is happening inside?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not an equality check (as you can clearly see from the results), it's an assignment:

```
a = ( a >> ( b = b << a ) );  //results in UB for negatives
```

An equality check is the simple

```
a == b;
```

Comment: But, if it's plain assignment, then how `foo()` is able to output correctly for all positive inputs? (sample output in question above)

Comment: @Manav coincidence? Why would you want this anyway? What's wrong with plain old `==`?

Comment: `foo()` seems to work perfectly with single digits numbers :)

Comment: @Manav: The expression can only return 1 if the left-shift overflows, in which case the behaviour is undefined. If you try the single-digit numbers that don't cause an overflow (0,1,2,3) then you should find that `foo(2,2)` returns 0.

Answer (score 5):

> Why it fails when one argument is positive and another negative?
>   What is the workaround in function foo() to display results correctly for all cases i.e. for all negative and positive arguments ?

The answer lies with in C99-Standard (ISO C99 : 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators):

> /4. The result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are filled with
>   zeros. If `E1` has an unsigned type, the value of the result is `E1 × 2E2`, reduced modulo
>   one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If `E1` has a signed
>   type and nonnegative value, and `E1 × 2E2` is representable in the result type, then that is
>   the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

So `foo(-2,-2)` is *undefined behavior*.

> /5. The result of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions. If `E1` has an unsigned type
>   or if `E1` has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral
>   part of the quotient of `E1 / 2E2`. If `E1` has a signed type and a negative value, the
>   resulting value is implementation-defined.

So `foo(-8,8)` is *implementation-defined*.

Comment: @Manav : simply that also is undefined behavior because shifting the number of bits more than actually occupied , the behavior is undefined

Answer (score 4):

Trying a few more values:

```
1,0: Equal
0,0: Not Equal
1,1: Not Equal
2,2: Not Equal
3,3: Not Equal
```

indicating that it isn't an equality check at all.

The expression has undefined behaviour, since it performs two unsequenced modifications of `a`. If we assume that your compiler evaluates it as if there were a sequence point after the left shift, i.e.

```
b <<= a;
a >>= b;
return a ? 1 : 0;
```

then it's quite easy to see that, unless `b` is zero, this always returns zero, *unless* the left-shift overflows, in which case behaviour is again undefined.